# Datatables: dynamic page load in modal, based on row values

Tags: javascript, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I am trying something really complex here, and I have not worked out a way to implement a solution yet. The part I work on looks like this:
1. simple page A that dynamically loads datatable from db.Last col is a button.
2. an html page B that loads different things according to 2 values stored at at local storage. these are available in the aforementioned table.

Now the part I cannot figure out:
3. Into the simple page A, there is a modal div. I want to load the B page into this modal on button click, and load different data, according to the values stored at local storage.

Here is my code so far:

```
function getadminprojects(){ //function that dynamically loads datatable

      $.ajax({
            url: "http://....../CustomServices/DBDistApps",
            type: "GET",

            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#projectsdt').show();

                projectsTable = $('#projectsdt').DataTable({
                  "pageLength": 10, 
                  "data": data, 
                  "scrollX": true,
                 "order": [[ 4, "desc" ]],
                  //"aaSorting": [],

                  "columns": [ 
                    { "data": "code" },
                    { "data": "descr" },       
                    { "data": "manager" },   
                    { "data": "customer" },
                    { "data": "link_date" },   
                    { "data": "delink_date"},
                    { "data": "type"},   
                    {
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-warning' onclick='openmodal2();'>button1</button>"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-success' onclick='localStorage.setItem('username',"+row.customer+");localStorage.setItem('projectid',"+row.code+"); projectpopmodal(); '>button2</button>"
                    },
                  ] , 


                });
                $('#projectsdt thead').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                    var data2 = table.row( this ).data();
                    alert( 'You clicked on '+data2[0]+'\'s row' );
                } );
                $('#projectsdt').show();
                $('#projectsdt').draw();
            }

      });

}

function projectpopmodal(){
    $('#showfreakinmap').load('newprojects.html');
    $('#fsModal').modal('show');
}//function to load page B into modal of page A
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: better hide that url. everyone can access the data now

Comment: can you give sample output.

Comment: Junar Jacob, in what form do you want it to be?